Voltage and current gain in two stage BJT amplifier
In the two stage amplifier bellow, by doing the DC analysis you will find the bias currents \$I_{C,T1}=3.71mA\$ and \$I_{C,T2}=5.48mA\$, if I am correct.

In order to find the voltage gain from Base T1 to Collector T2 \$\left( A_v=\frac{V_{C2}}{V_{B1}}\right)\$, I think we should follow the following steps, correct me if I am wrong:

We calculate \$\frac{v_{C1}}{v_{B1}}=A_{v1}=-g_m \left( R_C \parallel R_L \right)\$, since we have Common Emitter Configuration and \$R_e=0\$, since in the AC-analysis, the capacitor C2 becomes a shortcut.
We follow similar process to find \$A_{v2}\$
We have that \$v_{C1}=v_{B2}\$
Now we calculate \$A_v=A_{v1}\cdot A_{v2}\$

Now, what about the current gain?
The image bellow shows the AC-analysis I have done for the circuit by short-circuiting the capacitors and replacing the BJTs with the π model.

I find \$\frac{i_{C1}}{i_{B1}}=g_{m1}r_\pi\$ and \$\frac{i_{C2}}{i_{B2}}=g_{m2}r_\pi\$.
However how am I supposed to find \$\frac{i_{B2}}{i_{C1}}\$?
I thought about a current divisor, but did not know the resistance of the path with the current source.

Does R1 really connect T1 base to 10V?  Perhaps it should connect to T1 collector.

It's not a small signal model until you replace the 10 V source by its small signal equivalent.
Once you do that the analysis will be obvious.
